# Redis -Pub\Sub - Timed out connecting to Redis

Tags: ruby, redis

I have the the following ruby to subscribe to a channel.

When I set the host to 'localhost' I have no problems -i.e. script starts up

When I set to an IP address (where redis is running) other than localhost I get  a timeout.
   Timed out connecting to Redis
If I remove :timeout => 0 the script will run, however I believe this is the correct value to set for subscribers to ensure my client will never timeout.

How do I prevent timeouts occurring for a subscriber?

```
require 'redis'

$redis = Redis.new :host => 'IPADDRESS', :timeout => 0

$redis.subscribe('MyChannel', ) do |on|
  on.message do |channel, msg|
    puts "M is #{msg}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured redis to listen on the correct IP Address? By default it only listens on localhost. In the redis.comf you will find a line that says bind 127.0.0.1. Either comment it out to have redis listen on all addresses the system has, or change the localhost address to the address you want it to listen on.

Be aware that setting it to an IP will mean it only will be available on that IP.

Once you've made the change, restart the redis service. Then verify using redis-cli as described in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537254/redis-connect-to-remote-server/9219699#9219699)