# Celery + Redis losing connection

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have a very simple Celery task that runs a (long running) shell script:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ['CELERY_TIMEZONE'] = 'Europe/Rome'
os.environ['TIMEZONE'] = 'Europe/Rome'

app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis', broker='redis://OTHER_SERVER:6379/0')

@app.task(name='ct.execute_script')
def execute_script(command):
    return os.system(command)
```

I have this task running on server MY_SERVER and I launch it from OTHER_SERVER where is also running the Redis database.
The task seems to run successfully (I see the result of executing the script on the filesystem) but the I always start getting the following error:

```
INTERNAL ERROR: ConnectionError('Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.',)
```

What could it be? Why is it trying to contact `localhost` while I've set the Redis server to be `redis://OTHER_SERVER:6379/0` and it works (since the task is launched)? Thanks

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13928537/180960

Comment: Hi, it is already set to 0.0.0.0 and still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `backend` argument, `Celery` will use it as the result backend.
On your code, you tell `Celery` to use local redis server as the result backend.

You seen `ConnectionError`， because celery can't save the reult to local redis server.
You can disable result backend or start an local redis server or set it to OTHER_SERVER.

ref:

- http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results
- http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-result-backend