# redis with virtual machine

Tags: redis, virtual-machine

I created one symfony project in my local machine.I installed redis server in my virtual machine .In config.yml i added the following code for redis connection.
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://127.0.0.1

Now i am trying to connect my virtual machine with redis server,but still it is connecting to my local machine.

Can anyone explain me how to connect virtual machine with my local project?

Comment: This issue is not a redis issue. It's network/virtualization issue. E.g. with virtualbox, networking for/to/from the vbox is always a nat connection. It's impoosible to access it from host system. You need to use a network-bridge for example.

Comment: already have nat connection.In port forwarding i made guest ip as 10.0.0.5 and port 6379 and host ip,port as 127.0.0.1,7003 respectively.Then i added snc_redis: clients: default: type: predis alias: default dsn: redis://127.0.0.1:7003.Now also i am getting error 'connection refused'

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537254/redis-connect-to-remote-server/44027425#44027425